# attaching event handlers to react components using jquery

Tags: reactjs

I know this is the proper way to do -

1. Attach handlers on react components using attributes such as onClick, onBlur etc.
2. If attaching custom events then attach them in componentDidMount so that it always gets attached on every rendering.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation

However, what happens when an event is attached to a DOM element using jquery ? Why am I not able to listen to those events ? I am attaching them out side componentDidMount. However the event handler should get trigerred the first time atleast ?

I was debugging some react code which was attaching an handler to it directly, but it was not trigerring the handler at all. Why was that ?

Comment: Please show the code you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code example it's difficult to know for sure but more than likely you're trying to bind an event using jQuery to some react-generate DOM element.  So depending where you do the bind, you're probably using a jQuery selector which returns no results because React hasn't rendered that element to the DOM at the time the selector is being run.

This is why, if you are going to use jQuery binding, you should make sure you do so as part of the component lifecycle that ensures the element is actually rendered to the DOM before you are trying to select it with jQuery.  So that's why the recommendation is to put this kind of code inside `componentDidMount` and clean it up in `componentWillUnmount`.